# Javascript : Pass complex object to my controlleur (asp core)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, controller, http-post

Trying to send object to my controller :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Groups/Invite',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(UserInvited),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {},
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {}
        });
```

In debug mode, my data is :

{"Id":"47","Guest":[{"Key":"","Pseudo":"Lolo01500","Del":false,"Add":true}]}

My Action in controller :

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Invite")]
public IActionResult Invite(GroupInviteVM groupInviteVM)
{
  // TODO
  return Json(true);
}
```

And Targets object classes :

```
public class ItemInvite
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Pseudo { get; set; }
    public bool Add { get; set; }
    public bool Del { get; set; }
}

public class GroupInviteVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    List<ItemInvite> Guest { get; set; }

    public GroupInviteVM()
    {
        Guest = new List<ItemInvite>();
    }
}
```

When execute, only the Id is updated ...

Somebody could help me ?

T.Y.

Comment: Hi @Ipupi,How did you define `UserInvited`?And what do you mean for `only the Id is updated`?It seems there is no update operation in your `Invite` action.

Comment: Hi Rena. UserInvited is build in my js commit function (before call ajax). its value is {"Id":"47","Guest":[{"Key":"","Pseudo":"Lolo01500","Del":false,"Add":true}]} . but in my action, only the Id is initialized in my GroupInviteVM object... Guest is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When execute, only the Id is updated ...

That is because the `Guest` property is not public.Add public modifier like below:

```
public class GroupInviteVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ItemInvite> Guest { get; set; }//change this

    public GroupInviteVM()
    {
        Guest = new List<ItemInvite>();
    }
}
```

The whole demo:

View:

```
<script>
    var UserInvited = {
        Id: 1,
        Guest: [{
            Key: "aaa",
            Pseudo: "asd"
        }]
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(UserInvited));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Groups/Invite',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(UserInvited),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () { },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Invite")]
public IActionResult Invite([FromBody]GroupInviteVM groupInviteVM)
{
    // TODO
    return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: what am i dizzy !T.Y